# MSSQL SQL Server Connection String IP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm building my connection string in MSSQL connecting using The System.Data.SqlClient namespace in .NET.

I have a rather strange problem which I can't seem to fix.

The following connection string works fine when a connection is opened.

```
sql_connection_string="Data Source=(local)\\MS_SQL_METRICS;Database=thedatabasename;User ID=root;Password=mypassword;";
```

When I open the mysql connection it works fine using the above line.
What I want to be able to do is change the local field to an ip address. Note: If using the hostname this also works (but in my code I want the user to enter an IP, Not a hostname).

When I substitude local with the address 127.0.0.1 the connection fails to open.

```
sql_connection_string="Data Source=127.0.0.1\\MS_SQL_METRICS;Database=thedatabasename;User ID=root;Password=mypassword;";
```

I've also tried using the DBMSSOCN setting to use TCP/IP and still no luck. I.E

```
sql_connection_string="Data Source=127.0.0.1\\MS_SQL_METRICS;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Database=thedatabasename;User ID=root;Password=mypassword;";
```

The error message I get is 
*"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol)"*

Any help appreciated.

Comment: IS MS_SQLMETRICS the named instance or the server name? Do you get the same issue if you use localhost instead of the loopback ip?

Comment: @jcwrequests MS_SQLMETRICS is the instance name. The first string with Data Source=(local)\\MS_SQL_METRICS works. If I use Data Source=(localhost)\\MS_SQL_METRICS this fails.. It's very pedantic it seems but I haven't got a single IP address to work.

Comment: Are you sure you have ip protocol turned on sql server?

Comment: Can you connect to it using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @jcwrequests will have to check the ip protocol settings. Could well be the problem. Will check the settings in configuration manager and get back to you Thanks.

Comment: @jcwrequests You are correct.... IP Protocol was disabled. Working fine now via IP address. Would you like to submit is as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the ip protocol turned off. Just turn it on using SQL configuration.

Good Luck,

Jason